# Start an activity in UncaughtExceptionHandler API 26

Tags: android, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I am able to start an activity in UncaughtExceptionHandler on API 24;however, it doesn't work on API 26. I am trying to understand why it isn't working?

Thank you

EDIT:

```
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler _unCaughtExceptionHandler =
    new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SomeActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please, post a little of your code to give us an idea of how to help you to get this solved

Comment: API 26 introduced some related changes, are you following the recommended pratice? https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#loue

Comment: The only change I think it would affect is: "the system doesn't kill the app when an uncaught exception occurs?", and I am not sure why it is the case?

Comment: Can you please add some more code in your question and error log

Comment: What you are trying to do is difficult to get right, given that the app is in an unstable state at the time of the crash. I *strongly* encourage you to use ACRA rather than create your own crash reporting framework.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for the response. I just wanted to know why it's hard in API 26.